# set alarm on "my_package_replaced" when the alarm expires, this intent should be broadcasted

Tags: android, broadcast, alarm

I want to broadcast intent [action "my_package_replaced"] in my code, when alarm expires.

But when the alarm expires it was not broadcasting the above intent.

Comment: Your question is unclear. Do you mean you're trying to broadcast `MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED` yourself? 'cause you can't. Only the system can send that broadcast.

Comment: Is there a way to trigger the broadcast "MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED ". From the code.

Comment: No. [`Intent.ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html#ACTION_MY_PACKAGE_REPLACED)

Comment: Please show your code and explain what you have already done. Consider http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve

Comment: Actually, why are you even trying to do that? That is, why do you want to broadcast that particular action? I can't really see a point to it.

Comment: When the app is doing a particuler task, and at the same time if the upgrade is triggered. I want to postpone the upgrade with the help of Alarm and Broadcast it again.